# Maven building a jar with dependencies unpacked inside the JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, jar-with-dependencies

I have a problem with jersey 2.14 and nested jars and I can't figure it out. I looked it up and turns out its a bug with jersey which is still being fixed at the moment.

As a workaround I want to be able to use maven to build a jar with all dependencies unpacked inside my jar. I don't want to have JARs inside lib directory, I want classes. And I can't seem to figure out the maven plugin to do this with.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue. I had to use a built in workout of spring boot self. The really smart people there have figured out that there maybe problematic libraries like Jersey.

You have to use  configuration element of spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Put under  any jars that will be needed by Jersey (which have dependencies on other jars)

Example

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.my.Application</mainClass>
                <requiresUnpack>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>myapp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>service-commons</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </requiresUnpack>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or [Maven Assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) or [one-jar](http://one-jar.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/one-jar/one-jar-maven/).
Tutorials are here: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/

Comment: The problem is with a fat jar. spring-boot uses jersey and jersey has a bug where if you have a jar inside your far jar with dependency on another jar (inside the lib directory) jersey fails to scan that jar (with dependency on another jar). So my workaround is to have a jar with no dependency jars, rather unpacked classes. That way jersey can see the classes (which would otherwise be inside the dependency jar). So I need to build my far jar with unpacked classes rather than dependency jars.

Comment: As I remember, one of those plugins I've worked for me with Spring (not spring-boot but I think it's quite same). And that plugin does exactly what you want: unpacks all jars and places class-files into one

Comment: Probably you should start form Maven Assembly: you should be able to configure the exact behavior you want. I bet maven shade also unpacks all and then places classes, not jars into a resulting jar.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into Akceptor